# Проблемы с js Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Есть сайт.
[ссылка на сайт](http://dsb02.webazex.beget.tech/)
Когда заходишь сюда - видно отвал jQuery из-за ошибок в консоли, ошибки вызывают как по мне какие-то автогенерирующиеся скрипты WP.
[image: скрин с консоли]
Как только заходишь в админку и делаешь любое действие на сохранение чего либо (настроек, контента на странице, поста, прочее) - все ок. Разлогиниваешься - слетает. На хосте я нашел папку с этими скриптами, ее удаление ни к чему не приводит, она генерируется заново. Подключение стилей и скриптов делал как через functions.php, так и через header и footer напрямую, проблема остается. Кто знает как можно это поправить?

Код подключения скриптов и стилей

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'frukt_scripts' );
function frukt_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-frukt', get_template_directory_uri() . '/libs/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-frukt', get_template_directory_uri() . '/libs/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-frukt', get_template_directory_uri() . '/libs/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-frukt', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/animate.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'slick', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/slick.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'slick-theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/slick-theme.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-frukt', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-frukt', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/media.css' );


    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'modal', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'owl', get_template_directory_uri() . '/libs/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'fancybox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/libs/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'fancybox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/libs/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'matchHeight', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.matchHeight.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wow', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/wow.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'lazy', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lazysizes.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'common', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/common.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
//  wp_enqueue_script( 'masks', 'https://unpkg.com/imask', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slick', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slick.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
//  wp_enqueue_script( 'dev', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/tabs.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему, директория /s -- папка кеша, вы же наверняка что-то используете чтобы объединить скрипты и файлы стилей, как минимум. Я так понимаю что вы используете PageSpeed Ninja для этого, возможно какой-то другой плагин. Попробуйте деактивировать этот плагин, либо изменить некоторые настройки и посмотреть как это отразится на вашем сайте.

Comment: кэширование на стороне сервера отсутствует, проблема действительно оказалась в плагине